What are the differences between a thin and a thick duct wall?
As can be seen on this image, these two similar aircraft, though they have different prop size they also have very different duct wall thickness.

source source
What are the differences(performance, aerodynamics, etc) between having a thin vs thick duct wall?

G-FANS, I see what you did there

It looks like the first aircraft is a testbed for the small Turbomeca Astafan which was not developed further than the two prototypes. I wonder whether the nacelle was a complete one, the definitive full inlet duct might be missing. Here is what seems a more complete one.

The thickness of the duct wall is related to the radius of the inlet lip, but is not quite the same thing. A larger radius is better for off axis flow as in takeoff/climb. The more gradual turn of larger radius keeps the flow attached where the tighter turn of a smaller radius tends to make the flow separate, creating drag and reducing efficiency of the fan.
The opposite is true for high mach subsonic flow where more air is displaced by the large radius, tending to cause shock induced separation. The small radius is easier to keep shock free and has less of a problem.
In supersonic flow the large radius design creates a detached shock wave where the small/sharp radius can keep the shock attached to the lip, which is used to enhance pressure recovery in the inlet.


So the first aircraft in the picture is supersonic

@sophit . No guarantees anyone uses them correctly.
